# Permaculture Urban Transition

Tags: energy-efficiency, permaculture, city-living, defining-sustainability, vertical-gardening

In the more realistical and pragmatical way, which are the main steps a set of people in a medium sized urban envinroment, should undertake to convert the city to a permaculture oriented living style?

How much time realistically does it take to see it work?

Are there any real life successful examples?

Comment: "Main" steps, "first" steps. Maybe this is too broad. Personally, I think just start anywhere, especially with something you're good at. This is probably going to make the largest impact. Ah, and don't try to make people do what you do. You're not alone—respect the lifestyle of your neighbors and don't give them a reason to think of you and other people trying to live sustainably as a nuisance.